# Angular 2 - ngIf - Not a known property of div

Tags: angular

So I'm obviously new to ng2, as are a lot of people currently. With the release of the first version I have been learning a little. I am starting to get some of the more "ng2" ways of thinking down.

However, something as simple as `ngIf` I can't get to work.

This is my view:

```
<div *ngIf="testVariable" class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" formControlName="rememberMe" value="remember-me"> Remember me
    </label>
</div>
```

In my component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

...

ngOnInit() {
    this.loginForm = this._fb.group({
    username: ['', [<any>Validators.required]],
    password: ['', [<any>Validators.required]],
    rememberMe: []
  });

  this.testVariable = false;
}
```

Do I have to import something extra? I have seen pre-release ng2 examples importing `CORE_COMPONENTS` but I can't find a recent example with that in.

My module declaration:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { LoginComponent }   from './login.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ ReactiveFormsModule, CommonModule ],
  exports: [ LoginComponent ],
  declarations: [ LoginComponent ],
  providers: [ ],
})
export class LoginModule { }
```

Comment: You should include your module declaration since it is probably a module import which is missing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to add `CommonModule` in your application's `@NgModule`'s `imports`  declaration as below :

```
@NgModule({
  imports     : [
    CommonModule
  ]
})
export default class AppModule {}
```

Comment: The `CommonModule` is already exported by the `BrowserModule` that you import into the `AppModule`. The OP is probably using the component in a different module. In which case, the `CommonModule` should be imported into _that_ module, not the app module.

Comment: @peeskillet You are correct.  Where is it imported from?

Comment: @Aleski `@angular/common`

Comment: So, the above example was in `login.component.ts` are you saying I need to `import { CommonModule }` and then add that to the `@NgModule` decorator? Because I have done that and I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Have you declared your login component inside `declarations` of `@NgModule` ? can you share your module code here ?

Comment: I have added it now.

Comment: No. I am still getting the same issue :/

Comment: For which controller or template ? You have to declare all your module component inside declarations of `@NgModule`.Same thing applies for all other module also

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124769/discussion-between-aleski-and-ranakrunal9).

Comment: Ah sorry, it is working. For some reason I had `*ng-if` instead of `*ngIf` -... Silly me :D Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the BrowserModule to your module declaration. The directive [NgIf](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#ngIf) should be imported before its usage.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { LoginComponent }   from './login.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ ReactiveFormsModule, BrowserModule ],
  exports: [ LoginComponent ],
  declarations: [ LoginComponent ],
  providers: [ ],
})
export class LoginModule { }
```

Comment: Isn't this the same solution as `import { CommonModule }`? BrowserModule just has CommonModule in it and re-exports it. - And still not working...

Comment: It is the declaration from the generated module by Angular CLI. From what I understand, it contains more than CommonModule (see https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/modules/%40angular/platform-browser/src/browser.ts)

Comment: Yeah it does. Thanks for the help.